# Automatically pull docker image container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a linux bare-metal server with docker installed.

I work on an asp.net core project on my computer.

My source code is pushed on github.

Each time i commit and push something, github triggers a webhook on my docker hub account.

Docker hub builds me a new image which contains my asp.net core application binaries. (docker hub also run the tests)

This image works fine when i pull it manually on my server.

My question is how can i do this automatically ? Is there a way for my server to "detect" that docker hub contains a new version of the image and run something to pull this image and fire database migrations automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: are you working on remote machine or local system?

Comment: No. Docker won't do anything unless you ask it to pull the image again. Nor should it. There's all kinds of scenarios where you might push a new image, but not want to update the running container immediately or at all. It's on you to determine when and how that happens.

Comment: Thanks but what are the methods usually used for pulling new image without having to connect throw ssh ?

Comment: Run a cronjob that pulls the image?
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm not a docker expert, but isn't this what [watchtower](https://hub.docker.com/r/v2tec/watchtower/) does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you have a public ip which external internet such as `dockerhub` could visit you, then you can use [Docker Hub Webhooks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/):

  You can create webhooks like next diagram, set the url which external could visit your service, when image was pushed, it will post some json data to the url you afforded, one example data [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/#example-webhook-payload), then your own url could receive data and do related things as you like.

  [image]

  And, if you use jenkins, there are lots of plugin help you to do similar things: refer [Triggering Docker pipelines with Jenkins](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/triggering-docker-pipelines-jenkins), also [Polling Docker Registries for Image Changes](https://jenkins.io/projects/gsoc/2019/project-ideas/docker-registries-polling-plugin/)
- If you not have a public ip which `dockerhub` could visit, then I guess you had to poll dockerhub to see if new image there...